# How to ignore invalid value and set null value when use jackson paring json string from webfront?

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jackson2

Is there a good way to change the parsing strategy,even comes out a value cant convert to specific type just set null and continue parsing.

Here is the error info.

```
15:39:29 WARN  (DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java:424) Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.math.BigDecimal` from String "-": not a valid representation; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.math.BigDecimal` from String "-": not a valid representation
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1483] (through reference chain: com.vicson.SGHDGD.base.model.DailyOutputUpdatePojo["sheet0"]->com.vicson.SGHDGD.base.model.UpdateSheet["insertRows"]->java.util.ArrayList[1]->com.vicson.SGHDGD.base.model.DailyOutput["weekOutputDRatio"])
```

Comment: You are trying to fit a String into a BigDecimal... obviously it won't work

Comment: It is nothing to do with JSON but how did you represent `desh(-)` as numeric?

Comment: set null value and continue parsing,if string is invalid.

Comment: You don't. Handle the exception by registering an exception handler and sending a bad request response to the client with a suitably descriptive message.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way is to have String field that will be successfully deserialized from JSON. And then parse `BigDecimal` in setter/constructor that receives field value. Like this:

```
public void setWeekOutputDRatio(String value){
  try{
    this.weekOutputDRatio = new BigDecimal(value.toCharArray())
  } catch (Exception ignored) {
    this.weekOutputDRatio = DEFAULT_VALUE;
  }
}
```

Comment: invalid value can be any properties,so it cant solve my problem

Comment: this should be an accepted answer. the best solution is using validator for form parameters to not to pass invalid values to server-side, but this way is the simplest solution.